# Javascript: Google Maps API: Blank Map if map loads in a hidden container

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This seems to be a common problem, but is there a fix for the latest google maps API to show a map if it is in a container that is initially hidden?

Currently, I have map working when the container is displaying as block

```
<div class="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

If `.map-container` has `display:none;` initially on the CSS, and I use Javascript to "show" the container, then I see where the map should be, with a blank background and the google logo on it.

Has anyone found any good solution?  The only thing I can think of trying is initially loading it showing, then with javascript hide it when the page loads...  I don't want to do this obviously, so if there is another way, that would be great to hear!

Comment: Why not load when the element is shown? You could also use [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) if you don't need any kind of interaction.

Comment: Trigger the `resize` event on the map once the div is displayed.  You will need to set the center of the map as well (when the map has no size, the center is the upper left hand corner of the div...).  If that doesn't help, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue (and explain why it is different from all the other similar questions...)

Comment: The posted HTML is invalid.  `</map>` doesn't match `<div>`

Comment: @geocodezip, Thank you - that's just a simple mistake.  The code is sound, but I wrote that out as an example.  What you said above seems correct: "When the map has no size, the center is the upper left hand corner of the div"

Comment: @klauskpm, I do have interaction with the map and I even append locations to figure out a way point system.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the typo.

Comment: +1 for the title of your post. I did not realize that my map initialization code ran while the element was still hidden, until seeing your question

Answer (score 3):

Trigger the resize event on the map once the div is displayed. You will need to set the center of the map as well (when the map has no size, the center is the upper left hand corner of the div...)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pge7Lw82/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('dispmap'), 'click', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("map");
    console.log("before:" + elem.style.display);
    elem.style.display = (elem.style.display === 'none' ||
      elem.style.display === '') ? 'block' : 'none';
    console.log("after:" + elem.style.display);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
.map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="dispmap" type="button" value="toggle" />
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map">
    <div>

    </div>
```